# Sit yourself down VS. Sit down

Tags: vocabulary, verbs, phrasal-verbs

Sit yourself down

Sit down

Eventually, I am wondering if you as a native speaker feel any difference between those or not.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in literal meaning. **Sit down** is the more common phrasing. You would use **Sit yourself down** only under certain circumstances:

1) **Regional accent.** This formation is characteristic of certain regional accents or dialects.

2) **Informality.** The use of "yourself" would rarely be used in a formal setting; it might be used to convey informality: "Why don't you sit yourself down and stay a spell."

3) **Emphasis.** It can also be used to add emphasis to a command. "Bobby, you sit yourself down right now and stop that foolish talk."

Comment: As a native speaker, do you use these?